# I want to select the from values from database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How can i select values from database

Here is my code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->base_prefix . 'item WHERE uname = "'. $_POST['login_name'] . '" '; $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach($result as $results) {
   $results->salt;
   $results->password;
}
echo $sal->$results[0];
echo $pwd->$results[1];
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: both values($sal,$pwd) are blank..

Comment: please provide your full code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Sql Query in Wordpress as below.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM TABLE" );
foreach ($results as $result)
{
  $getdata[] = $result->$VALUE;
}
var_dump($getdata);
```